# SharePoint back to top: not able to add class on page scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, sharepoint

I am trying to add back to top to the SharePoint master page. Back to top functionality is working but on page scroll I am not able to add the class which is show/hide the icon. Below is the JS code

```
    if ($('#back-to-top').length) {
    var scrollTrigger = 100, // px
    backToTop = function () {
    var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (scrollTop > scrollTrigger) {
    $('#back-to-top').addClass('show');
    } else {
    $('#back-to-top').removeClass('show');
    }
    };

    $(window).on('scroll', function () {
    backToTop();
    });

    $('#back-to-top').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#s4-workspace').animate({scrollTop: 0}, 700);
    });
    }
```

Below HTML I have added in SharePoint master-page

`<a href="#" id="back-to-top" title="Back to top">&uarr;</a>`

Issue: Icon is not visible on page because its not able to add class show on scroll.

Comment: This works fine. Did you include jquery? http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LxzQzz

Comment: Yeah its included n yes its working fine in HTML but not in sharepoint

Comment: What version of SharePoint are you working with? If it's SharePoint 2010, have you tested your code against IE8? Do you get any error messages in the JavaScript debug console (F12)?

Comment: SP 2013. No error in console :(. I am getting undefined when I am typing var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop(); in console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For sharepoint instead of $(window) I used $('#s4-workspace') and its working

```
if ($('#back-to-top').length) {
var scrollTrigger = 100, // px
backToTop = function () {
var scrollTop = $('#s4-workspace').scrollTop();
if (scrollTop > scrollTrigger) {
$('#back-to-top').addClass('show');
} else {
$('#back-to-top').removeClass('show');
}
};

$('#s4-workspace').bind('scroll', function () {
backToTop();
});

$('#back-to-top').on('click', function (e) {
e.preventDefault();
$('#s4-workspace').animate({scrollTop: 0}, 700);
});
}
```